# Run ant code for all targets except one

Tags: ant

I have a common piece of ant code that should run for all targets except one. How is this possible, given that this code is outside any target and I cannot get the target name at this point?

I also am not allowed to pass any extra properties along with this specific target, so that I could wrap this code with an "if" based on whether this property is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a macro which embeds the common piece of code outside any target. And then call this macro, only when it is required. Since you already know that one target should not run this piece code, don't call the macro from that specific target.

Comment: Yes, but I have tens of targets. It gets tedious to add this for each target. But I guess I have no alternative.